# How is "no action needed" interpreted? (review queues)

Tags: discussion, review-queue

Does the previous actions by other users count in, as if it is like "no *more* action needed" or is it some kind of vote which is meant to indicate that it is OK, no matter what previous opinions are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just your vote, meaning that you think it is fine as it stands. If enough people agree with you, no action will be taken. But it still gives people with different opinions the opportunity to vote, too.